# Class member function with argument run asynchronously

Tags: c++, lambda, stdasync

I am trying to asynchronously run a member function, but I seem to have issues with every attempt.
Here is my code example:

```
A::A(){}
A::~A(){}
void A::asyncFunc(int i)
{
    std::cout<< i ;
}

void A::otherFunc()
{
    std::future<void> t;
    for(int i = 0; i<bigNumber; i++)
    {
        t = std::async(std::launch::async, &A::asyncFunc, this, i); // Problem code line
    }
}
```

With this code I'm being prompted with: "No instance of overloaded function std::async matches the argument list".

```
t = std::async(std::launch::async, static_cast<void(A::*)(int)>(&A::asyncFunc), this, i);
```

Same issue with explicitly casting it.
So I thought that maybe I can try lambdas.

```
t = std::async(std::launch::async, [=](){ asyncFunc(i); });
t = std::async(std::launch::async, [=](){ &A::asyncFunc(i); });
```

But this time I'm prompted with: "An enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list".

Do you know what I'm doing wrong in both cases?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/E3bMWsKP3

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code shown other than the use of undeclared `bigNumber` and missing headers.  Although, note that re-assigning to `t` in the loop will cause the the existing `std::future` to be destroyed with the associated [blocking behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future).

Comment: @G.M.  You guys are right. I'm having the code underlined with the displayed messages mentioned in the post, but it didn't even pass my mind to run it... I don't understand why they are underlined though as being wrong

Comment: *"I don't understand why they are underlined though as being wrong"* Odd as it seems, the editor might be using a differnt compiler for the code checks. Not the one you then use to build the executable.

Comment: Interactive error checking ("IntelliSense") of C++ is notoriously unreliable. Treat them as "to the best of my knowledge, but I could be wrong" guesses. (I personally switch them off.)